# How to switch scrollbar to dark mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const dark = document.getElementById("dark");

        dark.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const body = document.body;
        body.classList.toggle("ddark")
        })
```

```css
 html {
            height: 1000px;
        }
        body {
            background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar{
            border-left: 1px solid black;
        } 
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: white;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            border: 3px solid white;
            background-color: darkgray;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }
        .ddark {
            background-color: #303030;
        }
```

```html
<button class="darkmode" id="dark">Go Dark</button>
```

I want to switch scrollbar background color to dark mode when i click the button. When body goes dark, the right side of the page looks so ugly. How to make this?

Comment: Scrollbar customization is limited, and not the same for each browser. See [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/customize-the-browsers-scrollbar-with-css)

Comment: @Shrimp I know you are right, but if you check this website https://www.quora.com you can see that they made this so clear. And the website looks so good.

Comment: Seems to be [color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme)

From the link:
"When a user selects one of these color schemes, the operating system makes adjustments to the user interface. This includes form controls, scrollbars, and the used values of CSS system colors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added html instead of body and I also added html with the default scrollbar styling and it worked.

```js
const dark = document.getElementById("dark");

dark.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const body = document.querySelector("html");
  body.classList.toggle("ddark")
})
```

```css
 html {
   height: 1000px;
   background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
 }

 html::-webkit-scrollbar {
   border-left: 1px solid black;
 }

 html::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background-color: white;
 }

 html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border: 3px solid white;
   background-color: darkgray;
   border-radius: 20px;
 }

 .ddark {
   background-color: #303030;
 }

 html.ddark::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background-color: #ffffff;
 }
 html.ddark::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<button class="darkmode" id="dark">Go Dark</button>
```