# React - How to make the scrollbar track transparent on google chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, scrollbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5vw;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I made this code for a scrollbar in css and the scrollbar works, but for some reason that I don't know the scrollbar track isn't transparent on chrome.

i get that :
[no transparency  track scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOjXg.png)

But i want this result (transparency) :
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAFxB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try adding !important to the relevant place regarding changing only the background, as the code seems to be correctly structured like below it's looks like your body background

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

and if you have the multible them You need to switch theme like

```
.dark{
   background-color: #303030;
 }

 html.dark::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background-color: black; // or what color do you want to use :) 
 }
```

Comment: It will work perfectly for white-themed projects, but for black-themed projects, we need to give black color instead of transparent

Comment: Yep, you're right @raghava and you need to switch theme like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73372958/6052427

Answer (score 1):

```html
 1. you are using a black theme in your project, so if you give transparent it won't work, 
 2. you need to give a black color instead of transparent color
 3. simply change your code like this
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5vw;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: balck; <!--here you need to update-->
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

}
```